# Character conversion for database record

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Here is my row data:

```
A windy day looking at open houses Ã°Å¸Ââ€šÃ°Å¸ÂÂÃ°Å¸Ââ€šÃ°Å¸ÂÂÃ°Å¸Ââ€šÃ°Å¸ÂÂ https://t.co/8PCAMxJYaG
```

I need to convert the character encoding here to be a readable format.

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this, possibly using `php`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Declare utf-8 in your database connection to avoid bugs like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: That's a mess -- on beyond Mojibake.  Please do this to help diagnose:  `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...`

Comment: Any idea what language it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your database collation is correct. For accentuated values `latin-1` collation is your choice.

If it's right, mind sanitize your input and connection charset.

Cheers!

Comment: latin-1 or UTF-8. UTF-8 is better in Linux environments